# I don't understand how to input or divide float and int in simple calculator

Tags: c, calculator

This is the task

```
Input: 1 1 
Output: 2

Input: -1 -1
Output: -2

Input: 1.1 2.2
Output: 3.3
```

I know how to do 2 of 3 task, but I don't know how to include `float` numbers when I have `int` numbers.

Comment: Just do everything using `float`.

Comment: but there is difference between 2.0 and 2

Comment: Use `%g` to format the output — within broad limits, it will print the integral values as integers, without a decimal point, but print the floating point numbers more or less as you'd expect.  And it will print the numbers accurately outside the limits of exact integer values, for example.  (For example, `printf("%g %g\n", 2.0, 3.3);` produces `2 3.3`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%g` to get expected outputs that you have mentioned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num1 = 0;
    float num1 = 0;
    float tot = 0;

    printf("Enter number 1 = ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);

    printf("Enter number 2 = ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    tot = num1 + num2;

    printf("Output = %g", tot);

    return 0;
}
```

```
input : 2, 2
output :4

input : 5.5, 5
output: 10.5
```